# IBM runmqsc parameters with ssh getting null

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

```
 SERVER="192.1.1.1"
 QUEUE="QUSERV"
 CHANNEL="CHN001"
 COMMAND="display chstatus($CHANNEL) where(status eq RUNNING)"
RESULT=`ssh -n -i /home/admusr/.ssh/id_rsa -o ConnectTimeout=15 admusr@$SERVER "echo \"$COMMAND\" | /opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc $QUEUE | grep 'STATUS(RUNNING)' "`
```

echo $RESULT (comes blank)

Bash Script : the result is empty because the $QUEUE is assigned with "" when executing the script

Does anyone have some tip pls ?

This is the output for: `ssh -n -i /home/admusr/.ssh/id_rsa -o ConnectTimeout=15 admusr@$SERVER "echo \"$COMMAND\" /opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc $QUEUE grep 'STATUS(RUNNING)' "`

The output for above command is :

```
`grep STATUS(RUNNING)lay chstatus(QMBLUE1.QMRED1) where(status eq RUNNING)` /opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc QMBLUE1
```

Comment: I fixed the post with CHANNEL. I ran these commands inside my script and the result comes empty. #!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/ksh
....

Comment: yes. lets focus on ksh. its empty

Comment: I got error. " instead of `

Comment: it did not work. it lists only the full command

Comment: output updated :  grep STATUS(RUNNING)lay chstatus(QMBLUE1.QMRED1) where(status eq RUNNING) /opt/mqm/bin/runmqsc QMBLUE1

Comment: I tried a lot of times but with no success. Due my limited time project I had to find another solution. thanks for your help @JoshMc

Comment: I voted to close the question since you are not trying to get this working any longer, you as the opener of the question can close it yourself.